# query not returning data as expected in flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following lines of code attempting to return child values from a one to many relationship. Entries are confirmed in the database, with foreign key relationships

```
def SiteQuery():
    query = Site.query.join(SiteLocation, Site.id==SiteLocation.site_id).all()
    data = []
    for site in query:
        site_object = {
            'id': site.id,
            'name':site.name,
            'site_location': []
        }
        for site_location in site.site_location:
            site_location = {
                'id':site_location.id,
                'name': site_location.name
            }
            site_object['site_location'].append(site_location)
        data.append(site_object)
    return data
```

In another file, I have the following

```
class Site(db.Model):

    # Primary Model
    __tablename__ = 'site'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), index=False, unique=False, nullable=False)
    
    # # Site locations Relationship
    site_location = db.relationship('SiteLocation', backref='site', lazy=True)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Venue Name: {}>'.format(self.venue_name)
    
class SiteLocation(db.Model):

    #Primary Model
    __tablename__='sitelocation'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), index=False, unique=False, nullable=False)

    #RELATIONSHIPS
    site_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('site.id'), nullable=False)
```

My route calls it all nicely and I get output from a jinja template.

```
@site.route('/site')
def index():
    # return SiteQuery()
    return render_template('site.jinja2', data=SiteQuery())
```

My jinja looks like this:

```
{%for site in data%}
    Site Name: {{site.name}}<br><br>
    {% for sitelocation in site%}
        location name: {{sitelocation.name}}<br>
    {%endfor%}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

My output in my browser is this:

```
Site Name: the well

location name:
location name:
location name:

Site Name: three dollar bill

location name:
location name:
location name:
```

In other words, the child records aren't populating correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you populating the records?

Comment: I query the database and send that query as data to render jinja

Comment: the records are created through psql

Comment: If i query each table indivdually, and iterate in jinja, I see all my entries. I believe the error is somewhere in the SiteQuery() but I'm not sure exactly where.

Also if I backref from sitelocation to site in jinja, it works flawlessly. From many to one, everything is fine, it's the one to many that I'm stuck on.

Comment: `for sitelocation in site` should be `for sitelocation in site.site_location`

Comment: I knew it was something stupid! thank you so much!